# what is character and is there a difference from char? java

Tags: java, char, character

I was looking for a program that could return only numbers from a string containing letters and numbers and found the code below.
The program works perfectly, but introduces Character. 
To my understanding char is a single letter, number or any other sign in java, but I have never heard of Character. Is it the same as char or is it completely different? How do I use it (other than the way shown below)?

and what do I need to do if I want the print in int?

```
String something = "423e";
int length = something.length();
String result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Character character = something.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isDigit(character)) {
        result += character;
    }
}
System.out.println("result is: " + result);
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between int and Integer or booean and Boolean or long and Long ... ? They just wraps a value of the primitive type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Character`:

> The Character class wraps a value of the primitive type char in an
>   object. An object of type Character contains a single field whose type
>   is char.
>
> In addition, this class provides several methods for determining a
>   character's category (lowercase letter, digit, etc.) and for
>   converting characters from uppercase to lowercase and vice versa.

For example, `isDigit()` is a functionality provided by the wrapper class Character.

```
Character.isDigit(character)
```

Answer (score 3):

`Character` is a wrapper class for `char`, since `char` is a primitive type and thus isn't an `Object`. it fulfills the same role as `Integer` and `Boolean`.

Edit: It also provide a convenient class to store methods that deal with `char`s, like `isDigit()` in your example.

Answer (score 1):

char int are primitive data types where as Character/Integer implement Object class.
Java provides wrapper class Character for primitive data type char. Please check details [**here**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_characters.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is these just wrap a value of the primitive type.

Answer (score 0):

Character is a class that wraps an char as an object. Here is a link with more detail.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Answer (score 0):

Primitives are not object in java , So in order to treat them as object java provides wrapper classes